# Website Building Platforms - like weebly.com, yola.com, homestead.com

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to build/buy platforms that have the functionality like weebly.com or homestead.com or yola.com. Any ideas where I should look? Any suggestions? I want to host this platform for small business to build their websites for free - niche based, geographically categorized, etc. etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Why don't you check with those high quality providers you mentioned if they have any reseller plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla is a great open source platform and it definately fits into your "free" criteria. But there will be a learning curve if you're not familiar with that stuff. I personally hate Yola and Weebly. The websites just look ugly... Cubender (www.cubender.com) is a new product - seems interesting. They have a free trial and the sites look pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

try use a [cms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) to build this website , like [joomla](http://www.joomla.org)

Comment: What kind of effort (rough estimate) in terms of time and hours? Any idea?

Comment: the time depends on how much time you need to learn how to use it and how much time to customize it to fit your needs